# Sonarqube analysis from Drone.io in Github PRs

Tags: github, gradle, sonarqube, devops, drone.io

I'm trying to run Sonar scans at Github's Pull Requests from Drone.io.

This is the sequence:

1. PR is made
2. Drone.io build is triggered
3. Gradle task is executed
4. Gradle's Sonar plugin with Drone's environment is run

This is the command used in Drone's build:

```
gradle/wrapper all sonarqube \
 -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview \
 -Dsonar.github.pullRequest=$DRONE_BUILD_NUMBER \
 -Dsonar.github.oauth=<github_token>
```

I cannot find the PR ID in the Drone environment. Do you know if there is an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pull request number is available in the `DRONE_PULL_REQUEST` environment variable [1]

You can see a list of all environment variables by dumping them to your build logs. This can be done by adding the `env` command to your yaml:

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: golang
    commands:
      - env # dump environment variables
```

You will see something like this in your build logs:

```
...
DRONE_PULL_REQUEST=42
DRONE_BUILD_EVENT=pull_request
...
```

Note that the pull request is only set when Drone is building a pull request hook. You can confirm this by looking at the build event environment variable (above)

[1] http://readme.drone.io/usage/environment-reference/